# How Is It Possible That an App Connects to 0.0.0.142 IP Address?

Tags: malware, penetration-test

I regularly review connections being established from apps in my phone to external services. Lately, I found Facebook connecting to 0.0.0.142. So I deleted Facebook for Android app. Now, I just found that Instagram is connecting to the same weird IP.

Questions:

- What does this IP mean?
- Could this be a symptom of an exploited phone?
- What are other methods to know more about the effects of this attack (if it is)?
- How do I remedy the problem?

[Screenshot](https://m.imgur.com/mLf5thr)

Comment: Could that just mean host `142` (rightmost octet in IP address here) on your local network? Is that host your router?

Comment: That was on 3G. Gateway starts with octet 10. Not sure about 142 in the last octet. Not me though.

Comment: Is your device rooted? If it's, then consider [checking the hosts file](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60150/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file). Otherwise, it's quite difficult to find the cause.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.speedguide.net/ip/0.0.0.142

> Reserved and special use addresses:
>   0.0.0.0/8 - Current network (only valid as source address) RFC 1700

As it says i't just a way to represent the network in which you are. I think you shouldn't worry about it, but I'm not an android expert

Comment: I've read that; not convinced. Also, it says it should be a SOURCE address. In my case, it's the destination address.

Comment: Where does it say it's destination address? I don't know the app, but here http://sockstat.android.informer.com/ says it lists YOUR ports, not destination ones

Comment: The address isn't routable, is there any other suspicious connections? The app lists the remote end of the connections.

Comment: The ESTABLISHED tab shows all established TCP/UDP connections. The LISTENING tab shows listening ports on my device. So this means it's connecting to 0.0.0.142. Whether it's local or internet is not shown in the app.

Comment: No, there are no other clearly suspectious activities. But consider a dangerous threat model with moderate risk factor.

Comment: No, that's not right. LISTENING ports are ports opened in your device waiting for connections (Nothing connected at the moment), ESTABLISHED connections shows your local port to which some application/service is connected. IDK why you think it's the destination port

Comment: @Mr.E you are incorrect. The Established list shows the destination IPs.

Comment: Mr. E, you can confirm yourself by opening any Google app and see that it's connecting to Google's IP address range. And the ports are 443 for HTTPS (Server port.)

Comment: Download the app, apparently you're right (App description is wrong though). How are you connecting your phone to internet?

Comment: 3G at the time of finding this IP address in question.

Comment: I have just downloaded instagram app from google play and my IPs seems normal. You mentioned that it started with facebook app (Which you uninstalled). Are your instagram and facebook accounts linked? Or do you login at instagram with facebook account? Maybe your facebook or facebook app was compromised and it affected instagram through this

Comment: Possible. Which is why I posted the question. I need specifics from a malware analyzer if they've came across such case or a penetration tester. It's beyond suspicious.